# What Simulink input blocks do I need to to use to build such a system?

Tags: arrays, matlab, simulink, interpolation

I am relatively new to Matlab/Simulink, and so thankful to have such a forum to place my questions, which might be a touch trivial to you guys. Thanking you for your time, here you go.

This is in creating a Simulink model.

My input is a speed and a load, which is variable. And for each input point, I need to get a pressure curve as the output (Pressure vs Crank angle), the data for which I have and will need to feed in. What sort of blocks will I need to use, and how do I integrate both the arrays?

Second question, which would be for a next step. I have 4 such data point sets (speed v load). Is there a way I could interpolate them to the whole speed/load map?

Like I mentioned before, really a novice here, so any help would be highly appreciated. Thanking you guys again. \m/

Regards, 
Anirudh

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables containing your data in MATLAB workspace, the best way to get them into Simulink is to use "From workspace" block. See documentation at http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html. If your data is fixed and does not change over time use a Constant block. (http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/constant.html). "From workspace" block also allows you to interpolate missing data.

Answer (score 0):

Write the mathematical equations that model your system on paper, and implement them with Simulink blocks (best to start from higher order derivatives and integrate, rather than the other way round).

You may need/want to use a [1-D Lookup Table](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/1dlookuptable.html) if you have some non-linear relationship in your model. Any data/variable that is in your MATLAB workspace is accessible from your Simulink model, e.g. to parameterise the blocks in your model. As already mentioned, you can use the From Workspace block to use your data as input(s) to the model.

You might also want to check the [Getting Started](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/getting-started-with-simulink.html) guide for Simulink.